# Cable connector type identification

Tags: connector, identification

I would like to know what is the name of these type of Cable Connector's please, and where do I get them? and do they come in various sizes for the same Pin Count? also, I have another one with 4 Pins inside.

[image]

thanks.

Comment: I've seen the called 'circular DIN' connector. I sell them in 4, 6, 7 and 8 pin, male chassis and both female and male cable.

Comment: That connector looks like the male chassis mount Mic connector with screw collar retention. Look here: http://www.vetco.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=6558

Comment: What is the diameter?

Answer (score 1):

A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=circular%20multi%20pin%20connector) lead to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_connector).

If you look for circular connector on distributor websites you find something like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/circular-connectors/1443097). I believe they might be called "cannon-like connector" because the [XLR connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLR_connector) is sometimes called cannon connector because of his inventor, named [James Cannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon_family#James_H._Cannon).

Answer (score 1):

We just call this type connector "[Military connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Military_connector_specifications)". also it will be better if you say us that where have you seen it?

Answer (score 0):

Noticing the rough as-cast threads, that's the assembled shell and insert of a very cheap 8 pin male [microphone connector](https://www.google.com/search?q=microphone%20connector&espv=2&biw=1137&bih=783&tbm=isch&imgil=n9s9GyjZ6khhUM%253A%253BY1GWCRzsUT25iM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.topbontrade.com%25252Ftbm-type-electric-cable-connector%25252F90-tbm-type-microphone-connector.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=n9s9GyjZ6khhUM%253A%252CY1GWCRzsUT25iM%252C_&usg=__lb4tMv3DCZ1Oe8RxFiD9j-xrWYw%3D&dpr=0.9&ved=0CGkQyjc&ei=PclcVOquA4yNyATCxIHYDw#facrc=_&imgdii=0qWKfXkcOLMYdM%3A%3B1kVx3uyd-DyyOM%3B0qWKfXkcOLMYdM%3A&imgrc=0qWKfXkcOLMYdM%253A%3Bmt_WhyTbI-JKYM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.vetco.net%252Fcatalog%252Fimages%252FCAL-30-512M-1.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.vetco.net%252Fcatalog%252Fproduct_info.php%253Fproducts_id%253D9326%3B800%3B825). It could be either chassis-mounted or inline, depending on the associated hardware, which isn't shown.