# Missing connector name

Tags: connector

Someone can tell me the name of theese type of connectors? I need a standard name.
3.5mm diameter.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can see your answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/114793/cable-connector-type-identification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amphenol](http://www.fourstarwire.com/pro-audio--video-and-lighting-connectors.html)
Cylindrical, Mulit-pin connector.

Comment: Not sure what the drive by down vote is about, this looks like the right answer to me.